# Ограничение доступа к сайту с определенного домена с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, доступ

Верно ли следующее утверждение:
Если мой файл .htaccess выглядит так:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

То для того чтобы ограничить доступ к сайту с доменов auto-seo-service.org & autoseo-service.org и ничего не сломать мне нужно изменить его следующим образом:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?auto-seo-service.org.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?autoseo-service.org.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Если это не верно, то напишите пожалуйста, верное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) ограничить доступ к сайту можно несколькими способами.

По ip-адресу: `Require not ip 192.168.205`

По доменному имени: `Require not host phishers.example.com moreidiots.example`

По имени юзер-агента: `Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'BadBot'`

Выберете для себя подходящий вариант и протестируйте.